# How to use instance function as decorator in Python?

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

I have a `StatsVar` class to maintain the statistic variable, and a `Ctx` class to register the statistic variables as its attributes as follows.

```
class StatsVar:
    def __init__(self, v):
        self.v = v

class Ctx:
    def __init__(self):
        self.vars = list()

    def register(self, v):
        self.vars.append(v)
```

Create a `StatsVars` and register into an instance of `Ctx` by the following code:

```
ctx = Ctx()
var = StatsVar(0.)
ctx.register(var)
```

What I want to do:

- use a decorator to register the new instance of `StatsVar` into `ctx` (Rather than `Ctx`)

However, I don't know how to obtain the instance of `Ctx` (like `self`) to run `self.vars.append(v)` in the following code:

```
@Ctx.register
class StatsVar:
    def __init__(self, v):
        self.v = v

class Ctx:
    def __init__(self):
        self.vars = list()

    def register(cls):
        def wrapper(v):
            # !!! HERE, I know it's wrong, but how to obtain `self`?
            self.vars.append(v)
            return cls(v)
        return wrapper
```

**Update**

I found a feasible solution is to place `StatsVar` as an inner class and the creation of `StatsVar` is left to the instance of `Ctx` as follows:

```
class Ctx:
    def __init__(self):
        self.vars = list()

    def statsvar(self):
        manager = self
        class StatsVar:
            def __init__(self, v):
                self.v = v
                manager.vars.append(v)
        return StatsVar

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ctx = Ctx()
    ctx.statsvar()(0.)

    print('')
```

However, calling `ctx.statsvar()(0.)` seems terrible and is there any better solution here?

Comment: You could make a separate function that instantiates the `Ctx` class and then passes it back. I know that's not quite how you want it.

Comment: @Rashid'Lee'Ibrahim Thanks for your suggestion, and I update a solution. However, I still wonder if there is a more elegant solution here

Comment: Are you ever going to have more than one instance of `Ctx`? If not, perhaps you should create the instance before defining `StatsVar` so you can add the instances of the latter to the single instance of the former. Or you could do without the `Ctx` class all together, and just use global functions and variables. If you do want to be able to have multple `Ctx` instances, then it's going to be very hard for any decorator to do anything useful since there's no clear way for it to know which `Ctx` instance to register a new `StatsVar` instance to.

Comment: in the @-way you forgot the `@classmethod`

Comment: ... and `Ctx` should be defined before the `StatsVar` to perform sugar decoration

Answer (score 1):

Thinking in terms of sender and receiver, respectively `StatsVar` and `Ctx`, each instance of the sender "fires" a signal to the listener class. To do that, a function decorator can be used to intercept the sender-`set_v` and update the receiver-`set_vars`.

```
def send_register_signal(receiver):
    def wrapper(sender):
        setattr(sender, 'set_v', lambda self, v: (receiver.set_vars(v), setattr(self, 'v', v)))
        return sender
    return wrapper


class Ctx:
    vars = []
    @classmethod
    def set_vars(cls, v):   cls.vars.append(v)
    @classmethod
    def get_vars(cls):      return cls.vars


@send_register_signal(Ctx)
class StatsVar:
    def __init__(self, v):  self.set_v(v)
    def set_v(self, v):     self.v = v
    def get_v(self):        return self.v


# test
a = StatsVar(3)
b = StatsVar('smt')
c = StatsVar(7)
print(Ctx.vars)
print(b.v)
print(c.v)
```

Output

```
[3, 'smt', 7]
smt
7
```

**EDIT**

To be more consistent with the original question the decorator can be implemented directly in the receiver class.

```
class Ctx:
    vars = []
    @classmethod
    def set_vars(cls, v):   cls.vars.append(v)
    @classmethod
    def get_vars(cls):      return cls.vars

    @classmethod
    def register(cls, sender):
        setattr(sender, 'set_v', lambda self, v: (cls.set_vars(v), setattr(self, 'v', v)))
        return sender


@Ctx.register
class StatsVar:
    ....
```

Comment: setter and getter protocol can be omîtted but than the implementation is a bit less _natural_

Comment: Thanks, I think there are only two options to achieve my target. One is to 1) build `Ctx` as a singleton class, so that I can register variables within it or 2) register variables in the class level by building a class method. Both of them work, tks.

Comment: @david decorators are quite flexible and more than one ways exist, choose the one which you think has "better" syntax

Answer (score 0):

This can be a bad idea but you can use a singleton class like this below--

```py
class Ctx:
    _instance = None
    vars = list()
    
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if not isinstance(cls._instance, cls):
            cls._instance = object.__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instance

    def register(self, v):
        self.vars.append(v)
        

        
class StatsVar():
    def __init__(self,v):
        self.v = v
        Ctx().register(self)
        
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{self.v}'
        

ctx = Ctx()
StatsVar(0)
StatsVar(1)
StatsVar(2)

print(ctx.vars) # [0, 1, 2]
```